# Convert two columns of a dataframe into a Multi-Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, multi-index

I have the following dataframe:

```
          id    symbol          kline_start_time                 kline_close_time   open_price    high_price     low_price   close_price         base_volume  taker_by_base_asset_volume  taker_by_quote_asset_volume
0         236    BELBTC 2021-12-12 17:00:00+00:00 2021-12-12 17:59:59.999000+00:00    0.0000327    0.00003293    0.00003261    0.00003266  4.219400000000e+03          1.242200000000e+03           4.077191000000e-02
1         291   BONDBTC 2021-12-12 17:00:00+00:00 2021-12-12 17:59:59.999000+00:00    0.0003512    0.00035590    0.00035080    0.00035590  9.439700000000e+02          3.874500000000e+02           1.371697600000e-01
2         491  DEGOUSDT 2021-12-12 17:00:00+00:00 2021-12-12 17:59:59.999000+00:00    6.2600000    6.38000000    6.25000000    6.38000000  2.304267000000e+04          1.287461000000e+04           8.146284280000e+04
3         495  DENTUSDT 2021-12-12 17:00:00+00:00 2021-12-12 17:59:59.999000+00:00    0.0036200    0.00368500    0.00361300    0.00367000  3.868363360000e+08          2.088560540000e+08           7.630782654240e+05
4         522  DOCKUSDT 2021-12-12 17:00:00+00:00 2021-12-12 17:59:59.999000+00:00    0.0706000    0.07286000    0.07029000    0.07158000  3.661556000000e+06          1.757480000000e+06           1.259960511000e+05
...       ...       ...                       ...                              ...          ...           ...           ...           ...                 ...                         ...                          ...
163593  52691  MOVRUSDT 2021-12-23 08:00:00+00:00 2021-12-23 08:59:59.999000+00:00  180.9000000  190.00000000  180.00000000  184.20000000  3.029349000000e+03          1.926400000000e+03           3.592661830000e+05
163594    293  BONDUSDT 2021-12-23 08:00:00+00:00 2021-12-23 08:59:59.999000+00:00   15.9000000   16.95000000   15.85000000   16.45000000  5.232289000000e+04          3.188566000000e+04           5.267414258000e+05
163595   1620   WINUSDT 2021-12-23 08:00:00+00:00 2021-12-23 08:59:59.999000+00:00    0.0004668    0.00047090    0.00046640    0.00047080  3.791888251000e+09          1.836740019000e+09           8.610554246663e+05
163596    734    GASBTC 2021-12-23 08:00:00+00:00 2021-12-23 08:59:59.999000+00:00    0.0001295    0.00012990    0.00012550    0.00012570  1.859040000000e+04          8.756600000000e+03           1.120307510000e+00
163597    553   DOTUSDT 2021-12-23 08:00:00+00:00 2021-12-23 08:59:59.999000+00:00   27.1500000   27.46000000   27.12000000   27.42000000  3.193410800000e+05          1.466104100000e+05           4.004982870500e+06
```

It currently has the sequential index that you can see on your left.
Is it possible to convert it into a multi-index dataframe, the vertical index being the unique values of **kline_start_time** and the horizontal index being the unique values of **symbol** ? Note that **kline_start_time** has 256 unique values and **symbol** has 620 unique values.

Comment: I should mention that the issue I'm struggling with is automatically getting the data into the new df.
What I have up to this point is, considering the initial dataframe = df1


`unique_starts= df1.kline_start_time.unique()
unique_assets= df1.symbol.unique()
arrays = [unique_starts,unique_assets]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(arrays, names=["time", "asset"])
resulting_df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns = assets_1h_df.columns)`

which is organized the way I want it to be, but empty. So is there a way to automatically populate resulting_df with the correct data from df1 ?

Comment: What you expect is not clear. Can you update your post with a sample of your outcome?

Comment: I am afraid that would you want is not what is called a *multi-index dataframe*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for `pivot`?

```
value_cols = ['open_price', 'high_price', 'low_price', 'close_price', 'base_volume']
pivoted_df = df.pivot('kline_start_time', 'symbol', value_cols)
```

Maybe you just want:

```
new_df = df.set_index(['kline_start_time', 'symbol'])
```

**Update**

> if I would want it pivoted the other way round? meaning that instead of listing all symbols for each of the value_cols I'd want it listing each of the value_cols for each symbol ?

```
pivoted_df = pivoted_df.swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Obviously you can chain `df.pivot(...).swaplevel(...).sort_index(...)`

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: hey @Corralien - thank u so much for your answer! yes, it does seem to work, the first of your suggestions. I'm in the process of testing it rn.
Your second suggestion is really good, as well, the problem is in my original dataframe, both 'kline_start_time' and 'symbol' columns do not have unique values. That is to say, there are multiple symbols which appear for every kline_start_time and a symbol appears for each unique start_time. 
This results in 620 or so symbols, each appearing 256 times

Comment: sure. still in the process of running some tests which should not take much longer.

Comment: hey, just a quick question. if I would want it pivoted the other way round? meaning that instead of listing all symbols for each of the value_cols I'd want it listing each of the value_cols for each symbol ?

Comment: I updated my answer, can you check it please IIUC?

Comment: the update worked brilliantly, thank you :)
could u recommend a good resource on working with sliding windows to compute rolling indicators on an entire df, column by column?

Comment: It's really depend on what you want to do :) Look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/70459619/15239951. The best combo is often `rolling_transform`.